# How to start the Camel route using spring scheduler instead of camel timer

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

How to start camel route using spring scheduler instead of timer component?

I have tried using camel timer component to trigger the route but instead of timer is there any way to trigger the route using spring scheduler.

**1) Spring Main class:-**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleSchedulerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleSchedulerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**2) Router class:-**

Following examples where i tried with timer component.

```
//Directing to someService
from("timer://scheduler?period=10s")//What component should i use by default. 
.to("direct:someservice");

//Fetching datas from the rest api.
from("direct:someservice")                
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD).constant(HttpMethod.GET)              
.to("undertow:http://localhost:8090/api/employee/getemployees").
.log("Response : ${body}");

without timer, i can't able to trigger the route.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have called camel route using spring scheduler instead of timer by using ProducerTemplate
refer:https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/producertemplate.html.

1)Spring Scheduler:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private IntegrationService integrationService;

     @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 90000, initialDelay = 5000)
    public void integrationConfig() throws IOException {
        integrationService.getServiceAuthentication();

    }
```

2) Integration Service;

```
@Component
public class IntegrationService {
    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    public void getServiceAuthentication() {
 producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:someservice","username=123&password=123");
    }
}
```

3)Router Builder Class;

```
 from("direct:someservice")                
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD).constant(HttpMethod.GET)              
.to("undertow:http://localhost:8090/api/employee/getemployees").
.log("Response : ${body}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the scheduler component and configure it to use spring
https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/scheduler-component.html